# Hiding tooltip on link using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using a script to show links on my site and by default they show a tooltip on all links which I want to hide. Their support says:

> Every link has the CSS class "vglnk".  That makes styling them as easy
>   as adding one rule to your site's CSS.

For example, this would change the color:

```css
a.vglnk {
    color: #F7923C;
}
```

What code do I add which would hide the tooltip on links?

Comment: try this:   a.vglnk {display: none;}

Comment: That will hide the link entirely, not just the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Because the tooltip is likely handled via JavaScript, you may need to look at their implementation to figure out how to hide it.  There isn't really a standard CSS way to style tooltips.

Comment: Thanks - so it can't be hidden by CSS I guess then.

Comment: It might be possible to hide it, depending on how they implemented it.  For example, if the tooltip itself is a div that always has the same class separate from the anchor's class, you can do a `display:none` on the tooltip class.  But it is implementation-dependent.

Comment: yes it can be hidden.. use firebug or chrome's built in tools to find the class of the tooltip... If you have an url/example I can find it for you

Comment: If it is implemented as, say, a div with a style attribute using `!important`, a CSS file will not be able to override the style attribute and you will not be able to hide the tooltip with CSS alone.  You will need to hide it with additional JavaScript.  So it is implementation-dependent.  Maybe it can be done with CSS.  But it is not a certainty.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the HTML? Removing the `title` attribute from the link will remove the tooltip. If not, the script that you're using to show these links can also remove the `title` tag.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/X98n4/

Script:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

for( var index = 0; index < links.length; index++ ) {
    links[index].removeAttribute( 'title' );  
};
```

HTML:

```html
<a href="http://thinkingstiff.com" title="tooltip">thinkingstiff.com</a>
<a href="http://thinkingstiff.com" title="tooltip">thinkingstiff.com</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can just do a:link a:hover a:active a:visited for styling all your hyperlinks at once. I don't see any advantages unless you want some hyperlinks to be different. For those few you could use the div name they are in for example.

If you wanna hide tooltips you have to understand how hyperlinks work.

I can tell you this, every hyperlink has a title. Mostly the title is autofilled with the hyperlink title (in cases of rss). I also asume you are talking about rss here.
However if you want the tooltip to be gone add a title in your hyperlink and leave it blank.

title=" " and you good.

succes.

Comment: I just think about this. you could also try and see what happens.

a:title{
   display:none;
}

but i have not tried it nor do i have the time right now.
that way you only have to add a few lines on the css and not alter all your hyperlinks (unless you have a loop making the links).